# Will I regain resources by deconstructing my base?

Tags: subnautica

Mostly for more storage, I created a temporary base close to my rescue pod. It's lined with lockers and a fabricator, but before I add on to it anymore, using up all my titanium, if I deconstruct the base parts (hatch, platform, tube sections, etc) will I get the resources back? I don't have any extra pieces to test this on yet, and hoping to get an answer without potentially wasting more resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes. You do, in fact, get the resources back from deconstruction.

> If you want to deconstruct a Seabase module, equip the Habitat Builder and hold "E" while facing the module. The materials used to create the module will be returned to your Inventory.

[Source](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Seabases)

This is often always the best option, because it is fairly easy to run out of resources such as quartz. Once this happens, you must either brave the deep, deep caves for more, or deconstruct existing structures to regain resources.

Comment: There's a bug (I still see it on the current experimental release) that can cause you to not get all the resources back on occasion.  This can result in you getting locked inside your base if you deconstruct the last hatch from inside with limited resources available to you.